# 12.04 Browser fonts changed unexpectedly

Tags: 12.04, fonts, browser

running 12.04 and recently installed Font Manager and a handful of fonts that I use in Gimp.

After a recent reboot some fonts in both chromium and firefox are screwy.  This is only true on my ubuntu log in (and it happens in regular ubuntu and ubuntu 2d.)   On my daughter's profile, all fonts are still normal.

fonts on this page are all 100% ok (www.askubuntu.com)

But fonts on these pages have changed to one of my newly installed fonts.
facebook
google
yahoo (some)
gmail

I had MyUnity installed and chose restore all default fonts, but that had no effect.

Usettings no longer launches for me for some reason.

The fonts I installed were all put in to ~/fonts/

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear now that the installation of Font-Manager is what caused this problem.   I have not removed Font-Manager since I like it for previewing and hope to be able to keep using it.

So, I am not 100% sure I did this all correctly, but I renamed ~/.fonts.conf  to ~/.fonts.conf_bk

~/.fonts.conf looked like this:

*This file is maintained by Font Manager.
    If you wish to make any changes it is suggested you do so using
        /home/jdier/.config/font-manager/local.conf
    Any changes made to this file will be automatically relocated there
    at startup and any settings already in that file will be overwritten.*

It included listings of directories for fonts, but did not include anything in /usr/share so I think that is where the standard fonts are and when the system could not find them, it just grabbed some of the decorative fonts that I had installed into ~/fonts